# how to implement ajax and code in wordpress from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I made a search box in php and it works fine ... but when i implement it in wordpress it does not works correctly. I think the ajax is not working fine in wordpress.

I want to implement at it on cart page and want to get results also on same page.

```
//here is my form
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#form').submit(function() { 
    $.ajax({ 
        data: $(this).serialize(), 
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'), 
        success: function(response) { 
            $('#result').html(response); 
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
});
</script>




<body>
<form method="post" id="form" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="record" id="record" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)">
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="find">
</form>
<div id="result" style="height:50px;width:200px;"></div>




<SCRIPT language=Javascript>
       function isNumberKey(evt)
       {
          var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
          if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 
            && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
             return false;
          return true;
       }
    </SCRIPT>
```

//and here is my action file

```
$file = 'PINCODES DELHIVERY.csv';
if ($_POST) {
$searchfor = $_POST['record'];
if (!empty($searchfor)) {
if(strlen($searchfor)==6) {
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){

   echo "YES";
}
else{
   echo "NO";
}  
} else {
    echo "Enter valid zip code";
}
} else {
    echo "Enter Zip Code First";
}
}
```

can anyone help me. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: in ajax url pass full path of search.php file like this http://www.domain.com/wp-content/themes/site_theme/templates/search.php

Comment: for batter understanding check this tutorial of Ajax used with wordpress http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-started-with-ajax-wordpress-pagination--wp-23099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the provided information it's not possible to tell what's wrong. Could you provide a link to your site? What toes the console tab in Firebug (or another debuger, on chrome the network tab) tell you about the ajax request? Is it sent at all?

One thing you could try is to replace the `$` sign for jQuery with `jQuery` (the $ sign is used by other librarys too, that are maybe used by your template, or jQuery may runs in silent mode. Try this code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#form').submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            jQuery.ajax({ 
                data: jQuery(this).serialize(), 
                type: jQuery(this).attr('method'),
                url: jQuery(this).attr('action'), 
                success: function(response) { 
                    jQuery('#result').html(response); 
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: user2989952 Thanks for response ,
Here is my site's url : http://goo.gl/9TlYPW

Check form have placeholder "enter zip code" . It shows results on next page but we want to get the results on same page.

Comment: user2989952 Thanks, It works for me now thanks alot :)